# Run PHP function from HHVM C++ extention

Tags: php, c++, zend-framework, hhvm

Is it possible?
Without using Zend API, only Native.
For use it like in PHP extension:

```
call_user_function(EG(function_table), NULL, &func, &retval, 1, params);
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want [vm_call_user_func().](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/902cbf05e4392f560366f76e10b11c4185e3b17a/hphp/runtime/base/builtin-functions.cpp#L442)

```
Variant vm_call_user_func(const Variant& function, const Variant& params,
                          bool forwarding = false);
```

Depending on what your extension is doing at the time of the call, you likely will want to catch exceptions the function may throw.

```
try {
  vm_call_user_func(function, params);
} catch (const Object&) {
  try {
    raise_warning("got exception in my extension");
  } catch (const Object&) {
    // exception in error handler!
  }
}
```

`vm_call_user_func` knows how to handle the various ways PHP defines callables (e.g. `"SomeClass::someMethod"`, `array($obj, "method")`).

Depending on how the function to call is being provided, there may be more optimal ways. You could require that instead of any arbitrary callback, the user must provide a closure object. Since a closure object is always callable (i.e. you don't have to validate that `SomeClass` exists in my `"SomeClass::someMethod"` example), you can extract the underlying object, store it instead of the `Variant` and `vm_call_user_func()` will save some overhead decoding and validating it.